# What are the benefits of using prefix in keys in local storage when building client app? (especially in angularjs / angular apps)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, local-storage

Various libraries that provide an easy to use local-storage services (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage or https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage) give the possibility to set one common prefix for all created by that service keys in local-storage.

As the local storage is used preserved separately for each domain, it feels like there should be no threat that the keys will get 'conflicted' once using sub-domains (like test.youdomain.com or dev.yourdomain.com).

Therefore the question is - why and when shall we use a prefix in local-storage keys?

(I'm thinking that it might prevent for having conflicted keys when third party libraries in app use local-storage, but except that i can't think of anything else)

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing local storage keys helps identify whether keys belong to your app or to 3rd party libraries.

It is not required. But when you have a lot of keys it is better to prefix them.