# What is the naming convention for keys of AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In the official AsyncStorage example:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
Every key value has a `@myAppStore:` prefix.

`await AsyncStorage.setItem('@myAppStore:key', '{ "data": [...] }');`

However, in [Save sensitive data in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028755/save-sensitive-data-in-react-native/39112472#39112472), it seems Android and iOS both have their sandboxes, so the data is (kind of) secured.

Does the `@myAppStore:` prefix define the scope (eg. like creating a new collection in NoSQL), or it just a naming convention?

Comment: This is a useful question, I am also not sure if we should do the former or latter. I hope someone knows more about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733662/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-prefix-in-keys-in-local-storage-when-building-cli it is answered here, you can refer the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `@something` notation is nothing that actually does anything special to the content that you put into the storage. It rather is a nice naming convention that they use.

Having said this, I think you can use whatever you want there as keys, but I kept it there to make my code more readable and quickly see where I use the async storage.

I always use `AsyncStorage.setItem(@key,data)`  not `@name:key` because whatever you put in there as a field is indeed already the "key". Or the value under which your data is stored.

To store user and temporary key seems to be okay while I would not store backend keys.